# How many seconds need to pass before a 'loading bar' is warranted?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, mobile

Hello wonderful programmers of the world!

Forgive me in advance if you feel this is too subjective.

I'm building an app for the iPhone. At a certain point the user hits a button to process some data during which there is no animated feedback. Just the buttons disable and one button changes it's name to 'Processing data'. After about 5 or 6 seconds pass the buttons are enabled and life goes on.

Do you think I need some animation during this 'processing period?' Is there a rule of thumb about this? What would you say is the threshold for needing to include a 'loading bar' in your program? 5 seconds? 8 seconds? 2 seconds?

Thanks

Comment: Given that the buttons disable and the one changes its name, you probably don't, but I feel like if it takes more than about 3.5 seconds, a loading bar is nice just because it gives the user some feedback.

But, if you run the program with it and it slows it down, leave it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from [Response Time Limits](http://www.useit.com/papers/responsetime.html)

> The basic advice regarding response times has been about the same for thirty years [Miller 1968; Card et al. 1991]:
>
> - 0.1 second is about the limit for having the user feel that the system   is reacting instantaneously, meaning   that no special feedback is necessary   except to display the result.
> - 1.0 second is about the limit for the user's flow of thought to stay   uninterrupted, even though the user   will notice the delay. Normally, no   special feedback is necessary during   delays of more than 0.1 but less than   1.0 second, but the user does lose the feeling of operating directly on   the data.
> - 10 seconds is about the limit for   keeping the user's attention focused   on the dialogue. For longer delays,   users will want to perform other   tasks while waiting for the computer   to finish, so they should be given   feedback indicating when the computer   expects to be done. Feedback during   the delay is especially important if   the response time is likely to be   highly variable, since users will   then not know what to expect.

Answer (score 2):

5-6 seconds feels like an eternity especially when there isn't any notification going on.

I would wrap any operation that could take a bit of time even if it may be less than a second or two with a loading / progress / notification bar.

It's the best policy for keeping the end user from guessing if something is going on and to help them avoid the feeling your app isn't doing anything, is too slow and/or unresponsive.

Comment: Just be careful if your operation sometimes takes under a second and sometimes takes longer. If a progress bar is displayed for half a second before seeing the results, your app will feel .. nervous?

Answer (score 2):

Any action that doesn't give immediate, or almost immediate feedback is likely to cause the user to think that their iPhone, or worse, your application has frozen. Now, the fact that you have your button change to 'processing data' is good - That should mitigate most of that negative reaction, but I would add a simple animation just so your user feels like something is actually going on.

Answer (score 1):

The book "UI Bloopers" has guidelines on this.   0.1 second is enough to disconnect a response from an action.  1 second is enough to make a person in a conversation uncomfortable enough to start filling the gaps.  10 seconds is the maximum time we spend in unbroken thought on a single task.

Based on that they recommend if a delay will exceed 1 sec show a progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Anything longer than about half a second will feel to the user like your app has frozen. This time interval is a hard value to quantify, as it varies from person to person.

Do user testing to figure out the best time interval to wait for.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to do some form of usability testing. A couple of friends running your app can tell you if you've made some incorrect assumptions about user behavior.
2. If your app does some processing for more than about 0.1 (a value mentioned by others as well) then you need to make sure the user knows this and doesn't think the app "froze".
   For short delays (less than 1 or 1.5 seconds) an animated cursor should be just fine.
   If your app needs 5 or 6 seconds then you should use a progress bar.

The trouble with progress bars is that they need to show change. They don't really help if they're stuck at one third for 5 seconds and then fill completely in the last second. Make sure they are always "progressing" :)